# When will Naive Bayes misclassify continuous training instances?

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes

For the discrete case, we can say that Naive Bayes might misclassify training data due to things like the zero-frequency problem.

Why might Naive Bayes misclassify **continuous** training data?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the type of data, the independence assumption may fail (i.e., features may be dependent given a class) and give false results. Also none of the features may be relevant, while irrelevant ones will increase noise.

What is specific to continuous variables is the distributional assumptions that have to be made. Sticking to the normal distribution is often an oversimplification; nonparametric kernel smoothing-based density estimation has its own issues; by discretizing a continuous variable we clearly, at the very least, lose information.